# PHP analog to C++ member pointers?

Tags: php

Does PHP have something similar to C++ member pointers? I want to use a member of a PHP object, whose name (the member's, not the object's) I only know at runtime. For example:

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->NewMember = "value";

$member = 'NewMember';
// I don't know whether this is valid PHP,
// but you get what I'm trying to do.
echo $object->$member;
```

Comment: Its called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables in member calls.

```
$methodName = 'some_method';
$myObj->$methodName($param);
```

Not sure if this will work for what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
class Test
{
    public $foo = 'bar';
}

$var = 'foo';

$test = new Test();
echo $test->$var;
```

Edit: after your update, yes, that will work.

Answer (score 1):

No, PHP doesn't support (member) pointers. However you could use [Reflection API](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

```
class MyClass {
    public function doSth($arg1, $arg2) { ... }

    public static function doSthElse($arg1) { ... }
}

$ref = new ReflectionMethod('MyClass', 'doSth');
$ref->invokeArgs(new MyClass(), array('arg1', 'arg2'));

$ref = new ReflectionMethod('MyClass', 'doSthElse');
$ref->invokeArgs(null, array('arg1'));
```

As you can see in other answers you could also write:

```
class MyClass { ... }

$method = 'doSth';

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->$method('arg1', 'arg2');
```

But I really **don't** recommend that way. It's tricky, obscure and much harder to debug and maintain.

Comment: I don't want pointers. I want something that would help me achieve what I can achieve in C++ with member pointers.

Comment: @Crozin: I just need to implement a function that prints an array of similar objects to a HTML table. In that case, what advantages would using the Reflection API give me?

Comment: @Eduardo León: In this particular case it makes your code a bit more verbose and less tricky. Also handling errors should be easier.

Comment: @Crozin: I have *very* big problem. The properties I want to call are actually magic properties.

Comment: @Eduardo León: So they probably shouldn't be magic. Magic **is evil** cause it makes your code magic, and magic code is hard to understand and maintain. Magic mechanisms could be used in the case of some kind of fallback mechanism or to keep backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Crozin: Unfortunately, those magic methods are created by PHP's SOAP library. Not by me.

Comment: @Eduardo León: Well... magic methods can be accessed like any other (`$obj->__call('methodName', array('args'))` so you'd have to reflect `__call` method.

Comment: @Crozin: Fortunately, I found a way around it using anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code I'm setting the `$memberToGet` at runtime:

```
class Person
{
  public $foo = 'default-foo';
  public $bar = 'default-bar';
}

$p = new Person();

$memberToGet = 'foo';
print "The Person's $memberToGet is [" . $p->$memberToGet . "]\n";

$memberToGet = 'bar';
print "The Person's $memberToGet is [" . $p->$memberToGet . "]\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

By passing $this as a variable by reference, you can access members of that class.

Comment: Adding an ampersand, &, to the variable name, thus something like: &$this.   However I'm going by memory so that may not be completely accurate.